# How can I make Icons scale well with higher UIScale in Java 9?

Tags: java, swing

In my software it must be possible for icons to look good with higher UI scaling. Currently, they look pretty blurry when I set the scaling to 1.1 or higher.

My icons have variable sizes, but most of them are 16x16 pixels.  I use Swing ImageIcons and Java version 9.

I just tried to make the icons look "better" by saving the icons as 32x32 pixels and scaling them down to 16x16 during runtime with the hope that enough information is preserved and it looks nice. But it didn't work.

How can I make my icons look good with 16x16? Or is that just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create icon sets for each supported size.Since icons are quite small, rescaling won't work well.
In Swings applications, I usually create my icons as SVG (which is a vector format and can be rescaled without loss of quality) and use [batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) to generate the bitmapped icons I need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have most of the Icons as SVG aswell. But I am concerned with the performance issues that may arise if I scale the SVG for 1000+ Icons. Is Batik working well performance wise?

Comment: I usually create them at startup. But since you have many icons I would suggest you  create an swing app that generates ready-to -use images, and include that generation in your build process.